# Google Plugin for Eclipse only one direction?

Tags: eclipse, google-apps-script, google-plugin-eclipse

I'm using the Google plugin for Eclipse and have imported a Google Apps Script project. The Google project is updated immediately when I edit and save the local version, but the opposite doesn't seem to happen. When I edit files in the project directly in the Google code editor, it never seems to be reflected locally.

Does the plugin only work in one direction?